# How to use Liberty 8.5.5.9 Docker

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

we believe new Websphere Liberty 16.0.0.2 has an important bug related to JAX-RS 2.0 client, which prevents standard REST calls from apps deployed to work. The last version we know to be this bug free is 8.5.5.9, but Dockerfile of the official Docker by IBM has already been updated to 16.0.0.2

Even though we use Dockers, I am no Docker geek. Is it possible to specify in my Dockerfile in first line:

```
FROM websphere-liberty:webProfile7
```

That I want the version of the Docker that includes 8.5.5.9 and not the last one? Which one would it be? (other Docker, like Solr, explain the different versions in the doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the 'tags' tab on Docker Hub you will see that there are other historical tags still available including websphere-liberty:8.5.5.9-webProfile7. Note that these images represent a snapshot in time e.g. they are not rebuilt when new versions of the base Ubuntu image are created. The intention is that Liberty provides zero migration and therefore you should always be able to use the latest. You have obviously found the counter-example...